# Match Comparison OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have come to love this syntax in OCaml

```
match myCompare x y with
|Greater->
|Less->
|Equal->
```

However, it needs 2 things, a custom type, and a myCompare function that returns my custom type.

Would there be anyway to do this without doing the steps above?

The pervasives module seems to have 'compare' which returns 0 if equal, pos int when greater and neg int when less. Is it possible to match those? Conceptually like so (which does not compile):

```
match myCompare x y with
| (>0) ->
| (0)  ->
| (<0) ->
```

I know I could just use if statements, but pattern matching is more elegant to me. Is there an easy (if not maybe standard) way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there an easy … way of doing this?

No!

The advantage of `match` over what `switch` does in another language is that OCaml's `match` tells you if you have thought of covering all the cases (and it allows to match in-depth and is compiled more efficiently, but this could also be considered an advantage of types). You would lose the advantage of being warned if you do something stupid, if you started using arbitrary conditions instead of patterns. You would just end up with a construct with the same drawbacks as a `switch`.

This said, actually, Yes!

You can write:

```
match myCompare x y with
| z when (z > 0) -> 0
| 0 -> 0
| z when (z < 0) -> 0
```

But using `when` makes you lose the advantage of being warned if you do something stupid.

The custom type `type comparison = Greater | Less | Equal` and pattern-matching over the three only constructors is the right way. It documents what `myCompare` does instead of letting it return an `int` that could also, in another language, represent a file descriptor. Type definitions do not have any run-time cost. There is no reason not to use one in this example.

Comment: +1, though I believe the motivation for the question was that OCaml itself is -- unfortunately -- using a signed integer for comparison operations.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg I realized that after writing my answer/rant. Well, Caml should really have a `Greater | Less | Equal` type and use it for all `compare` functions. And it would save us from people writing `let compare_int x y = x - y`, too (not a transitive relation because of overflows).

Comment: It really is quite a shame that compare returns like that :( +1 though, very useful write up

Comment: Nitpick: the last clause cannot be guarded, so one should (for instance) place `0 -> 0` at the end.

Comment: @Aristide In OCaml 4.14.1, `let f x =  match x with  | z when (z > 0) -> 0  | 0 -> 0  | z when (z < 0) -> 0` is accepted and only results in “Warning 8 [partial-match]: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive”. This warning is also emitted if `0 -> 0` is placed last.

Comment: Yes my bad, the last case should be `_ -> 0` to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a library that already provide those variant-returning compare functions. This is the case of the [BatOrd](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatOrd.html) module of Batteries, for example.

Otherwise your best bet is to define the type and create a conversion function from integers to comparisons.

```
type comparison = Lt | Eq | Gt
let comp n =
  if n < 0 then Lt
  else if n > 0 then Gt
  else Eq

(* ... *)

match comp (Pervasives.compare foo bar) with
  | Lt -> ...
  | Gt -> ...
  | Eq -> ...
```